# "Qof, Qof" What does this mean?

Tags: hebrew, synagogue, symbols-symbology

An old (formerly used) synagogue building in my town has this sign on the front of it:

[image: Aged synagogue sign, saying, in Hebrew, the letter 'qof' twice, followed by "*Shaaray Torah*".]

The text says "Shaaray Torah", the name of the congregation, but what is the meaning of the two qofs above it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Likely, it is an acronym for קְהִילָה קְדוֹשָה *k'hila k'dosha* (lit: holy congregation), a title for Jewish communities whose use dates back to the Talmud ([Tamid 27b](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9661&pgnum=54)).

Comment: Or Kahal Kadosh

Comment: Can you specify what your link says on the topic?

Comment: @WAF It uses that phrase as a title for a Jewish community...

Comment: I believe the phrase there is "_kahala kadisha_", which is an Aramaic translation of @ElShteiger's suggestion. Does "_k'hila k'dosha_" appear there as well?

Comment: @WAF It says קהלא קדישא as you can see. Are you complaining about my gender?

Comment: Asking, not complaining. It seems a little misleading to source the phrase thusly when the one that appears there is a different one, albeit with the same initials.

Comment: My local community/synagogue is called Kahal Kadosh Shaar Hashamayim

Comment: @WAF I said "likely". I'm not sure if שערי תפילה considers itself to be masculine or feminine, or if it's in an Aramaic speaking locale.

Comment: This just got interesting. Are you implying that _kahal_ and _k'hila_ are actually masculine and feminine versions of the same word?